# How to call a procedure in Hsqldb using the Database Manager?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, hsqldb

I'm trying to find a way to call a procedure in the Hsqldb Database Manager. I'm using the version 2.3.4.

I'm trying to use:

```
DECLARE value NUMERIC;
call MY_PROC('1', 1, DATE '2012-12-31', TIMESTAMP '2013-12-31 00:00:00', 1, value)
call value
```

But I receive the error:

```
dynamic parameter or variable required as INOUT or OUT argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the correct way is execute each statement **separately**: write the first statement then execute, write the second one then execute, etc.